# How to update multiple fields of an array object with one request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

```
{
   _id:xxxxstoreid
    store:{
        products:[
            {
                _id:xxxproductid,
                name:xxx,
                img:url,
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

since i cannot predict the request for update, params may have just name or it may have both.

here is my query,it updates successfully but it removes other fields if they are not present in the params.
eg:

```
var params={_id:xxid,name:'xxx',img:'xxx'}
```

or

```
var params={_id:xxid,name:'xxx'}
```

in this case if params have just name it removes img field and updates.

```
User.update({'store.products._id':params._id},{$set:{"store.products":params}},callback);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to supply the multiple keys to [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) with the [positional `$` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) to update both matched keys.

I prefer the modern ES6 way of object manipulation:

```
let params = { "_id" : "xxxproductid", "name" : "xxx", "img" : "yyy" };

let update = [
  { 'store.products._id': params._id },
  { "$set": Object.keys(params).filter(k => k != '_id')
    .reduce((acc,curr) =>
      Object.assign(acc,{ [`store.products.$.${curr}`]: params[curr] }),
    { })
  }
];

User.update(...update,callback);
```

Which would produce the call to MongoDB as ( with `mongoose.set('debug', true)` ) turned on so we see the request:

> Mongoose: users.update({ 'store.products._id': 'xxxproductid' }, { '$set': { 'store.products.$.name': 'xxx', 'store.products.$.img': 'yyy' } }, {})

Where basically you take your input `params` and supply the `_id` as the first argument for the "query" :

```
  { 'store.products._id': params._id },
```

The rest takes the "keys" from the object via [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) which makes an "array" which we can "filter" with [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and then pass to [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to transform those keys into an `Object`.

Inside the [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) we call [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) which "merges" objects with the given keys, generated in this form:

```
  Object.assign(acc,{ [`store.products.$.${curr}`]: params[curr] }),
```

Using the template syntax to assign the "current" (curr) "key" into the new key name, again using the [ES6 key assignment syntax `[]:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) which allows variable names in object literals.

The resulting "merged" object is passed back to be assigned to the "root" object where `$set` is used for the key of the update, so the "generated" keys are now children of that.

I use an array for the arguments purely for debugging purposes, but then that also allows cleaner syntax on the actual `.update()` using the "spread" `...` operator to assign the arguments:

```
User.update(...update,callback);
```

Clean and simple, and some JavaScript techniques that you should learn for object and array manipulation. Mostly since the MongoDB query DSL is basically "Objects" and "Arrays". So learn to manipulate them.

Answer (score 2):

```
function updateProducts(params) {
    var query = {'store.products': {$elemMatch: {_id: params._id}}}
    var updateObject = null;
    if (params.name && params.img) {
        updateObject = {$set: {'store.products.$': params}}
    } else if(params.name && !params.img) {
        updateObject = {$set: {'store.products.$.name': params.name}}    
    } else if (params.img && !params.name) {
        updateObject = {$set: {'store.products.$.img': params.img}}  
    }

    User.update(query, updateObject, callback)
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Also, I forgot to mention, the `products` field is an array, so you can't access properties on it. Your question needs more detail, like what exactly what you are calling params is.

Comment: in mongoose there is a way of doing findOne and save ryt?

Comment: so in this case  how can i do that? as u said products is an array , how will i know which index to update?
should i loop products and match it with params?

Comment: I'm not familiar with mongoose so I can't answer that part.

Comment: Use the positional operator to update an element in an array if you are not sure what element in an array you need to update. See [here] (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)

Comment: okay , thanks for spending your valuable time . am upvoting it for now .

Comment: No problem. So to clarify, you need to check what params contains first to decide how to set the object in the array, using the positional operator linked in the above comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148082/discussion-between-madhvesh-s-and-andrew-winterbotham).

Answer (score 1):

The below query will use [`$`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) positional operator to locate the array element  at index found from matching the array by `_id` in the query document followed by updating the fields for the element with the `params` values.

```
var params = {_id:1, name:'xxx',img:'yyy'};
var id = params['_id']; // Get id to locate matching array index
delete params['_id']; // Remove id from the object
Object.keys(params).forEach(function (key){params['store.products.$.'+key] = params[key]; delete params[key];}) // Transforms remaining object keys to include the positional $ placeholder to { "store.products.$.name" : "xxx", "store.products.$.img" : "yyy" }

User.update('store.products._id':id},{$set:params},callback);
```